# how to convert List of object to jsonObject?

Tags: android, json, list, gson

**how to convert List of object to jsonObject ?**

> I am converting a list of Pojo class to jsonObject . I converted whole list  to jsonArray, but how can i add additional fields out of the array scope?

```
            List<Order> items = new ArrayList<>();
            if (checkOutList != null) {
                for (Category.Items i1 : checkOutList) {
                    Order order = new Order();
                    order.setC_id(i1.getCid());
                    order.setItem_id(i1.getItem_id());
                    order.setQuantity(i1.getCount());
                    items.add(order);
                }
                Order order = new Order();
                order.setOd_total_cost(cardValue.getText().toString().trim());
                order.setR_id(checkOutList.get(0).getRid());
                order.setU_id("5");
                items.add(order);

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(items).getAsJsonArray();
                Log.e("order", myCustomArray.toString());
            }
```

**above code gave me output:**

```
[{"c_id":"3","item_id":"18","quantity":"5"},{"od_total_cost":"Card Value: $30.14","r_id":"1","u_id":"5"}]
```

**output i want**

```
{"items":[{"quantity":"25","c_id":"70","item_id":"10"}],"r_id":"5","u_id":"70","od_total_cost":"20000"}
```

**update**

```
JsonElement jsonObject=gson.toJsonTree(order);
Log.e("order", myCustomArray.toString()+jsonObject.toString());
```

> above one line added gave me below out put now how to add arrayname:items? and add whole output as json object

```
[{"c_id":"3","item_id":"18","quantity":"5"},{"c_id":"3","item_id":"17","quantity":"2"},{"c_id":"2","item_id":"91","quantity":"2"},{"c_id":"2","item_id":"9","quantity":"1"}]{"od_total_cost":"Card Value: $20.16","r_id":"1","u_id":"5"}
```

Comment: Have to create a new POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other ways are also valid, but I you could also use a POJO for it.

```
    class WholeObject{
        List<Order> items;
        String r_id;
        String u_id;
        String od_total_cost;

        //---getters and setters---

    }

    WholeObject wo = new WholeObject();
    wo.setR_id("5");
    wo.setU_id("70");
    wo.setOd_total_cost("20000");
    wo.setItems(yourOrders);

    Log.e("order",  new Gson().toJson( wo ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Json object and add the values as below

```
 List<Order> items = new ArrayList<>();
        if (checkOutList != null) {
            for (Category.Items i1 : checkOutList) {
                Order order = new Order();
                order.setC_id(i1.getCid());
                order.setItem_id(i1.getItem_id());
                order.setQuantity(i1.getCount());
                items.add(order);
            }


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(items).getAsJsonArray();
            Log.e("order", myCustomArray.toString());




     JsonObject ob= new JsonObject();
        ob.put("items",myCustomArray);
        ob.put("od_total_cost",cardValue.getText().toString().trim());
         ob.put("r_id",checkOutList.get(0).getRid());
         ob.put("u_id","5");


       Log.e("order", ob.toString());
```

Comment: **remove /** {"items":"[{\"c_id\":\"3\",\"item_id\":\"18\",\"quantity\":\"5\"},{\"c_id\":\"3\",\"item_id\":\"17\",\"quantity\":\"3\"},{\"c_id\":\"2\",\"item_id\":\"91\",\"quantity\":\"2\"},{\"c_id\":\"2\",\"item_id\":\"9\",\"quantity\":\"1\"}]","od_total_cost":"Card Value: $20.18","r_id":"1","u_id":"5"}

Comment: @beginner are you adding mycustomarray.tostring to jsonobject?

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
new Gson().toJson(yourObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below.

**Step 1:**
Add the dependency below and sync your gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

**Step 2:**

Add the two classes below in your model package.

**MyItem.java**

```
public class MyItem {

    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<Order> mItems;
    @SerializedName("od_total_cost")
    private String mOdTotalCost;
    @SerializedName("r_id")
    private String mRId;
    @SerializedName("u_id")
    private String mUId;

    public List<Order> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Order> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    public String getOdTotalCost() {
        return mOdTotalCost;
    }

    public void setOdTotalCost(String odTotalCost) {
        mOdTotalCost = odTotalCost;
    }

    public String getRId() {
        return mRId;
    }

    public void setRId(String rId) {
        mRId = rId;
    }

    public String getUId() {
        return mUId;
    }

    public void setUId(String uId) {
        mUId = uId;
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
public class Order {

    @SerializedName("c_id")
    private String mCId;
    @SerializedName("item_id")
    private String mItemId;
    @SerializedName("quantity")
    private String mQuantity;

    public String getCId() {
        return mCId;
    }

    public void setCId(String cId) {
        mCId = cId;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return mItemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        mItemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return mQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        mQuantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Put the code below in your class where you want to convert your object into a string. Here, I am just making this in my main activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setQuantity("25");
    order.setCId("70");
    order.setItemId("10");
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
    orderList.add(order);
    MyItem myItem = new MyItem();
    myItem.setItems(orderList);
    myItem.setRId("5");
    myItem.setUId("70");
    myItem.setOdTotalCost("2000");

    String str=covertObjectToString(myItem);

    Log.e("Tag","Reseponse String "+str);
}

private String covertObjectToString(Object object) {
    return new Gson().toJson(object);
}
```

Done.

I hope you are clear with my logic.

Comment: i had already added gson but i had to just make extra pojo class to maintain list .. thank u

Comment: see accepted ans it was been answered before u .. so i just up votes yours